# Some confusions about Command Line Compiler and MSBuild

Tags: c#

[C# CSC.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)

If we give it a C# file, a .CS , is it able to compile it and say for example a ";" is missing at line 12 of your code? In a form that later in my program - which is Java RCP app, I can show those compile errors in a Spreadsheet

How about MSBuild? Is that able to show compile errors same as my previous example?

Comment: Are you asking if csc.exe will compile something even with a compile-error?  The answer to that is no.  Or are you asking if csc.exe can return a list of errors? The answer to that is yes.  Your question is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say this is your code (program.cs):

```
namespace MyCustomBuild
{
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World")
         }
     }
}
```

You can call `csc program.cs` and receive the following output

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

program.cs(7,52): error CS1002: ; expected
```

Alternatively you can use msbuild to achieve the exact same result!  Here is the content of `build.msbuild`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Default">
     <Csc Sources="program.cs"/> 
  </Target>
</Project>
```

You can then call your msbuild file with varying levels of verbosity, as shown.

`msbuild build.msbuild /verbosity:quiet` and `msbuild build.msbuild /verbosity:minimal`

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.269]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

program.cs(7,52): error CS1002: ; expected [<filePath>\build.msbuild]
```

`msbuild build.msbuild /verbosity:normal`:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.269]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 6/6/2012 12:13:00 PM.
Project "<filePath>\build.msbuild" on node 1 (default targets).
Default:
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /out:program.exe program.cs
program.cs(7,52): error CS1002: ; expected [<filePath>\build.msbuild]
Done Building Project "<filePath>\build.msbuild" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"<filePath>\build.msbuild" (default target) (1) ->
(Default target) -> 
  program.cs(7,52): error CS1002: ; expected ["<filePath>\build.msbuild]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.28
```

The remaining two verbosity levels are detailed and diagnostic and they present even more information if you want it.  I'm not sure how much information you want for your spreadsheet, but hopefully one of these works for you.

Answer (score 4):

Think of MSBuild as a glorified `make` or something more like `ANT` - it is a language for describing compilation/build tasks. When you use MSBuild for building your c# program, you are actually using `csc.exe` for the compilation part.

Comment: Thanks. "is it able to compile it and say for example a ";" is missing at line 12 of your code? In a form that later in my program - which is Java RCP app, I can show those compile errors in a Spreadsheet " ?