# Compiling VS 2012 project programmatically?

Tags: c#, resources, resx, csc

I have this class library project sitting in a solution.

My need is to be able to embed resources (all files from 'Resources' folder) into DatabaseResources.resx and compile it all into an assembly, on the fly.

[image]

I tried CSC and was able to compile it

```
csc /target:library /out:MyClassLibrary.dll  /res:ContentChangeLog.gz /res:CountryBillingRules.gz /res:Finance.gz /res:Instructions.xml /res:Language.gz /res:Masters.gz /res:wbs.gz /res:wbsList.gz
```

But, MyClassLibrary.dll should be exposing these resources thru DatabaseResources.resx so that others can find it- MyClassLibrary.DatabaseResources.(resource name)

[image]

I couldn't find a way to do the same with CSC.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: A DLL is a pretty miserable "database".  Surely the real problem is with "others can find it"?  Those others have to use the ResourceManager class, a notoriously fickle class.

Comment: [The XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you have most likely chosen whrong solution to your problem. Ask about the problem, not solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is MsBuild.

a good explanation here - [Some confusions about Command Line Compiler and MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917219/some-confusions-about-command-line-compiler-and-msbuild)

Comment: MSBuild was what I was looking for. Thanks Rex.